# R: Mahalanobis implementation in cmeans [e1071]

Tags: r, fuzzy-c-means

I was just wondering if there is a way in cmeans function [in package e1071] to perform the clustering using the Mahalanobis distance?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have your answer or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply. I had tried using the mahalanobis dist into the fanny function. However, I was not sure if these two functions perform similar custering to the data and what is the difference between the membership exponent in fanny and the  m fuzzification in cmeans. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The `e1071` package does not have a mahalanobis option.  However, you can look into the `cluster` package and the `fanny` function.  As per the help page, it also computes a fuzzy clustering of the data into k-clusters.  With this function, you can provide your own distance matrix.

So for mahalanobis distance, you can calculate your distance matrix with `dist` and then run your clustering.

```
require(cluster)
set.seed(123)
x<-rbind(matrix(rnorm(100,sd=0.3),ncol=2),
         matrix(rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=0.3),ncol=2))
y <- dist(x, "mahalanobis")
fanny(y, k=2)
```

Given your understandable concerns over equivalence between the functions here is an example comparing them:

```
require(e1071)
cl<-cmeans(x,centers=2,iter.max=20,dist="euclidean",method="cmeans",m=2)
fl <- fanny(x, k=2, maxit=20, metric="SqEuclidean", memb.exp=2)

> head(cl$membership)
             1           2
[1,] 0.9948729 0.005127121
[2,] 0.3647778 0.635222221
[3,] 0.9290126 0.070987385
[4,] 0.7588260 0.241174043
[5,] 0.9282550 0.071745007
[6,] 0.9599231 0.040076886
> head(fl$membership)
          [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 0.9948722 0.005127775
[2,] 0.3647890 0.635211040
[3,] 0.9290171 0.070982905
[4,] 0.7588304 0.241169649
[5,] 0.9282575 0.071742489
[6,] 0.9599221 0.040077878
```

Although not absolutely identical, you can see there are very close.  You will also notice that fanny is specifying the squared euclidean distance which is what cmeans is doing.  This equivalence is noted on the fanny help page `?fanny` under metric.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the package `e1071` does not have the `mahalanobis distance` but you can use this piece of code to calculate it in any case:

```
x <- data

center <- colMeans(x)  # Center (mean vector)
cov_matrix <- cov(x)   # Covariance matrix
y <- mahalanobis(x, center, cov_matrix) # new distance created
```